# Clicking on a response to my meta post in my inbox takes me to the main IoT page

Tags: bug, meta

When I click a meta post in my inbox, it just takes me to http://iot.stackexchange.com and does nothing else. No error messages.

What is wrong? Every meta post from IoT does this. None of the other site do. It's been happening ever since the private beta started.

> **update: it's happening again, always happens at least the first time I log in.** The second time, it seems to work normally. I'm now sure it's a bug.

**Edit:**

I've now inspected tbe HTML code. The link appears to refer to meta but when I click it it takes me to the main IoT page.

## HTML Code

```
<a href="http://meta.iot.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/266?noredirect=1" class="js-gps-track" data-gps-track=", site.switch({ target_site:667, item_type:7})">
                            <div class="site-icon favicon favicon-iotmeta" title="Internet of Things Meta"></div>
                            <div class="item-content">
                                <div class="item-header">
                                    <span class="item-type">comment</span>
                                    <span class="item-creation"><span title="2016-12-28 05:56:44Z" class="relativetime">6 hours ago</span></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item-location">
                                    Accepting Nominations — Who should moderate this site?
                                </div>
                                <div class="item-summary">
                                    Best of luck :)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Chrome 54 (seems like you're quite unlucky with bugs!). Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Aurora0001 Firefox 50.0.2

Comment: What happens if you 'Inspect Element' on the message in your inbox and look for the nearest `<a href="...">`? Where does the link point to?

Comment: @Aurora0001 Something just changed, and it wasn't me!! it's working now (???)

Comment: Just blame caching! It's always at fault. You can always bump this by editing if you get it again.

Comment: FF 50.0.2 here too but no problems.

Comment: @Ghanima happened again

Comment: @MarkYisri did you try inspecting the source when it happened?

Comment: @Aurora0001 duh, forgot!! don't worry, it'll happen soon :)

Comment: @MarkYisri no problem, but I suspect it will really help the SE team to tell what went wrong (and whether it's a browser issue or a SE issue)

Comment: Will try to lure a community manager here (in time). Please describe the issue as detailed as possible by editing the question.

Comment: [It's a known bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260784/auto-login-to-private-beta-redirects-to-the-home-page).

Answer (score 6):

I experienced a similar bug (Firefox 50.0.2). The following happened:

1. I made an account on IoT (because I like to spy on private betas).
2. Somebody linked this very question somewhere else.
3. I clicked the link and landed on the main page (not Meta).
4. I reproduced this behaviour a few times.
5. I visited Meta manually.
6. I clicked on the link again and was taken here (where I should be taken).

Comment: Somebody thanks you for reporting your related issue ;)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft For me, it seems that the second click always works, regardless of whether I enter meta first.